# Repeating Sequence of numbers

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args){

int a;
for(a = 1; a < 100; a++){

    int r = a%7;

    System.out.println(r);

}
```

I wrote this down in Java to get a repeating sequence 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 . . . .

And what I am wondering is how to pick up and print out one of repeating nubmers in the sequence?

For example, how do I print out 3rd number in the repeating sequence?

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: What specifically are you asking other than 'someone do my homework'?

Comment: Can you clarify more what do you mean "print out 3rd number "? does it mean not printing the others?

Comment: `System.out.println(3 % 7);`? (If this wasn’t what you meant, you need to explain.)

Answer (score 4):

Save the numbers in an array and then pick the desired one:

```
int[] arr = new int[100];
for (a = 1; a < 100; a++) {
    int r = a % 7;
    arr[a] = r;
}
int k = 3;
System.out.println(arr[k]); //print the number at index 3;
```

Comment: For the simplicity of the example, I chose an array. :)

Comment: @LKTN.25, this will indeed print the 3rd number in the sequence. Note that the loop starts from 1, not from 0. Thanks for the downvote, also.

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov ok my bad but, where `i` came from on your answer `arr[i] = r;` it should be `arr[a]=r;`. I remove my downvote. sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use mod 7 of the desired index

```
 int yourIndex = 4;

 int yourResult = yourIndex % 7;
```

Also, always put spaces between operators!
(eg. r = a % 7;)